# How to sorting by date string with mat-sort-header without using sortingDataAccessor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-table

I have a Angular Material DataTable with sort headers (two columns - dates as strings). Everything is working correctly now:

html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns"[matColumnDef]="column">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [mat-sort-header]=column.property>{{column.header}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item[column.property]}}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

ts:

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  switch (property) {
    case 'from': return new Date(item.from);
    case 'to': return new Date(item.to);
    default: return item[property];
  }
};
```

But from documentation:

```
Note that if the data properties do not match the column names, or if a more complex data property accessor is required, then a custom sortingDataAccessor function can be set to override the default data accessor on the MatTableDataSource.
```

So, how can I get away from using sortingDataAccessor and fix the html so that the sorting works correctly?

p.s. Maybe I need to enter something like "column.sortProp" and do a check on fields with dates, substituting mat-sort-header for them.

Comment: Why exactly do you think you shouldn't use `sortingDataAccessor`? From the given sentence I read the opposite.

Comment: I'm talking about the case where the data properties match the column names

Comment: If your date format's [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) matches it's chronological order (e.g. ISO-8601), then you can get away without using `sortingDataAccessor`. Otherwise, the `or if a more complex data property accessor is required` part of your quote applies, and you need to resort to using `sortingDataAccessor`.

Comment: TotallyNewb, ty. How to do it? Instead of a loop, should I define each field in html or only dates field?